# How do I add an inline style (specifically border width) to a div element?

Tags: html

Here is my task first and foremost:

At the top of the page body, insert a div element with the id "header" containing the inline image "mlogo.jpg". The aternate text for the image should be "Mayer Photography". Insert an inline style that sets the border width of the image to 0 pixels.

So that's my task  and here is what I have come up with:

```
<body>
  <div style="id=header width: 0px"><img src="mlogo.jpg" alt="Mayer Photography">  
  </div>
</body>
```

I don't know if I'm entering the style attribute correctly to set the width. That's my biggest dilemma I think. And also I'm not sure but I'm thinking the div element should be written like this instead:

```
<div id="header"><img src="mlogo.jpg alt="Mayer Photography">
   <style="width: 0px"> 
</div>
```

If you could help me out that'd be awesome! Thanks.

Comment: Yea and I'm still new at grasping HTML.

Comment: Maybe it's time to read your textbook?

Comment: ceejayoz- I have but it still doesn't hurt to ask when you're stumped.

Comment: Mark the correct answer as the answer.  Don't update your title.

Comment: @Ashley Did you look up 'inline style' in the back of the book? I find it hard to believe that you'd be given homework without having the subject covered in either lecture or assigned reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div id="header">
  <img style="border:none;" src="mlogo.jpg" alt="Mayer Photography" />
</div>
```

An inline style is done as an attribute within the tag you're trying to style.
You want the image to have no border, that's why you apply the style there.
A zero width border is no border.  So simplify by saying "border:none;".